# Catching an event fired from a managed dll in a native C++ COM component

Tags: events, interop

I'm writing a managed .NET dll, that is called from native c++ code (Similarly to what is done here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736).

The thing is this: As a part of the .NET logic an event should be fired, and I want to catch that event in a handler placed in my C++ code.

I've searched the web and was not able to find a thorough and clear explanation of how this is done. Can you offer help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3.aspx) one?

Your native C++ code is the event sink and your managed object(firing the event) will be the event source.

Comment: Basically this is indeed what I need, but the thing is that here the client side (the sink) is implemented in VB, and what I need is the parallel C++ code, which is not that trivial to conclude here. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I thought the client was C++(that's what the title says). Unfortunately I don't know VB, you can try a VB to C++ translator like this one http://www.metamorphic.com/products.htm#VBToCPPProductDescription not very cheap though